# Can't find Custom Metadata Records in Change Set Components

Tags: deployment, change-set, custom-metadata, unlocked-package

I have Custom Metadata Records, the Type being in an unlocked package, which I want to add to an Outbound Change Set.
I have all Custom Metadata Types enabled for my Profile (even necessary?), but still can't see the Records I am looking for.
I can see other Custom Metadata Records in form of "CustomRecordType [package]", but not the ones I want to deploy.

Is there a setting I am missing? Visibility is set to public.

Comment: According to the [metadata coverage report](https://mdcoverage.secure.force.com/docs/metadata-coverage/53/CustomMetadata/details) you should be able to include custom metadata. I wonder if it is because the custom metadata type is from an unlocked package that you can't see the records from it...

Comment: Yes, the thing I don't understand is, why I see other metadata records, which are also in an unpackaged metadata type.

Comment: Could the problem be due to the unlocked package newly installed on the current org (I'm guessing it is a sandbox) and not already installed on the org from which the sandbox was created? (Grasping at straws here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the labelling. I already had a Custom Metadata Type with the same label and namespace prefix. Changing the label of one of the Types resolved the issue.